# Regular expressions and signs

Tags: c#, regex

The input which is passed to my method must have have desired number of signs. The minimum number of signs is specified dynamically by another input parameter. So I have prepared an expression which is used for confirming the input but the problem is that it cannot find the sign character inside the string and it returns a false value.
According to the MSDN :

> [character_group] , Matches any single character in character_group.
>   By default, the match is case-sensitive.

and

> {n,}, Matches the previous element at least n times.

My method :

```
public static bool HasSign(int minimChar, string input)
        {
            _pattern = "[!@#$%^&*()_+={}[]\\|?/.><,~`]{" + minimChar + ",}";
            rgx=new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(_pattern);
            var res = rgx.Match(input);
            return res.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example to work with, eg input string, the minimchar string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character class ends prematurely here and the whole pattern is "broken":

```
_pattern = "[!@#$%^&*()_+={}[]\\|?/.><,~`]{" + minimChar + ",}";
                             ^
```

It is matching a char from the `[!@#$%^&*()_+={}[]` character class, and then a *sequence* of subpatterns (`` \\|?/.><,~`]{2,} `` - 1 or 0 `|` chars, `/`, any char but a newline, `>`, `<`, `,`, `~` and `` ` ``, and then 2 or more `]` symbols).

See [what string it matches](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b!%40%23%24%25%5e%26*%28%29_%2b%3d%7b%7d%5b%5d%5c%7c%3f%2f.%3e%3c%2c%7e%60%5d%7b2%2c%7d&i=!%2f%c2%a7%3e%3c%2c%7e%60%5d%5d).

You need to either escape the `]` inside, or put it at the character class beginning and use a verbatim string literal in order to use `\\` to match a backslash:

```
_pattern = @"[]!@#$%^&*()_+={}[\\|?/.><,~`]{" + minimChar + ",}";
           ^  ^                ^^
```